# Google Sheets Concatenation Questions (Referring to a Cell Within a Formula)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to turn this formula:

```
=(ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30="ETH",Transactions!$K$2:$K$30,Transactions!$F$2:$F$30)))/(SUMIF(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30,"ETH",Transactions!$F$2:$F$30))
```

So that "ETH" can be turned into a cell reference (A2) instead. I've tried so many different methods but they all do not work and instead return "0". Here are what I've tried:

```
=(ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30&"="&""""&A2&""""&","Transactions!$K$2:$K$30,Transactions!$F$2:$F$30)))/(SUMIF(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30,&""""&A2&""""&","Transactions!$F$2:$F$30))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just A2 without all the `"`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  =(ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30=$A$2,Transactions!$K$2:$K$30,Transactions!$F$2:$F$30)))/(SUMIF(Transactions!$E$2:$E$30,$A$2,Transactions!$F$2:$F$30))
```